# Где view из mvc в андроид приложении. Document-view. МVP.

Tags: java, android, mvc, mvp

Возьмем просто андроид приложение : класс наследующий Activity в этом классе подключается layout и подписываемся на события от кнопок. И по определенному событию загружаем текст из базы и отображаем.   Я так понимаю класс наследующий Activity это контроллер. Модель у нас например пассивная,  а значит только сообщает view о том,  что произошли изменения, но как? Вернее куда?  Сообщить модель может только в контроллер и он уже вызовет метод setText, чтобы в TextView например отобразить загруженные данные.  Выходит контроллер и View тут объеденены? Но раз так, то получается это не MVC, а его логическое продолжение Document-View, архитектурное решение, где представление объеденено с контроллером,которое как раз часто и используется в средах где можно наносить формы (кнопки, всякие контроллы) на UI. И сейчас я понимаю, что mvc то тут нет, хотя говорят что логика андроид построена как раз на mvc. Может она где то в другом месте на mvc ? Где?   Ну и еще вопрос как продолжение оттого: document-view обладает минусами типа  плохой тестируемости представления с совмещенным контроллом или невозможности заменять представления и призван решать эти вопросы MVP.  В нем можно поменять представления, но как?  Принимать в конструкиоре layout'ы чтобы уменьшить связность с представлением или тот факт что мы можем в onCreate прописать другой layout уже считается той возможностью подменять представления, которая есть в mvp.  В общем помоги разобраться с этой кашей у меня в голове

Comment: Android не основывается на MVC. он основывается на "тяп ляп и в продакшн" паттерне.  Если вас интересует роль компонента андроида в архитектуре MV* (активити\фрагмент) то это всегда View. Всю логику из них максимально выносим

Comment: Вы вопросы четко сформулируйте, а то каша из вашей головы теперь тут) В MVP view - activity\fragment\view , presenter - прослойка между view и моделью, model - классы для работы с БД, сетью  или просто какая-то логика, отдающая данные. View ничего не знает о model и не имеет на него ссылок, равнозначно как и model не знает о View. Presenter знает о всех. В presentor не должно быть кода из платформы андроид (это крайне желательное условие, но иногда, конечно, его невозможно выполнить).

Comment: Sviat Volkov, компонент андроида это имеется ввиду класс наследуемый от Activity ? Вот логику обработки событий мы из него ведь не вынесем? Выходит в андроид контроллер получается пересекается с view ? И View в этом компоненте основной,  а элементы контроллера нужно максимально выносить,  только куда? В отдельный класс,  который будет иметь экземпляр  активности... ну так вообще не верно..

Comment: Danilka37, ну вот презентер как от view отделить в андроид?

Comment: как это не вынесем? вы вешаете на вьюху клик лиснер допустим, и там в коллбеке один метод presenter.doSomething(). MVC в андроиде никто не использует. Смотрите на MVP. а лучше на MVVM. В сети множество статей с примерами